# Saving image from canvas to server. Blank image getting saved

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, canvas

I have the following code for creating an image from equation editor and on clicking save button displaying it in a canvas
After display, I wish to save it
It displays alright, but saves a blank image
Please let me know where I am going wrong

**Javascript code**

```
btn_save.onclick = function() 
{ 
var canvasimg = document.getElementById("canvas");
var eq = document.getElementById("equation");
var context = canvasimg.getContext("2d");
var imgurl;

context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasimg.width, canvasimg.height);
context.drawImage(eq, 0, 0, 50, 50);

imgurl = canvasimg.toDataURL("image/png");
imgurl = encodeURIComponent(imgurl);

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.build-exam.com/imgsave.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(imgurl); 
}
```

***PHP code***

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");            // to get POST data
if($postdata)
{
  print_r("came in postdata");
  // Get the data
  $imageData=$postdata;

  // Remove the headers (data:,) part.
  // A real application should use them according to needs such as to check image type
  $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);
 // $unencodedData= $imageData;
  $filteredData = str_replace(' ', '+', $filteredData); 
  // Need to decode before saving since the data we received is already base64 encoded
  $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
  echo "unencodedData".$unencodedData;

  // Save file. This example uses a hard coded filename for testing,
  // but a real application can specify filename in POST variable
  $fp = fopen( 'd:\\Apache2.4\\htdocs\\imgfile.png', 'wb' );
  fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
  fclose( $fp );
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't encode the data URL.

Comment: I tried without encoding. It still saves a blank. Is it that toDataURL initialises the canvas

Comment: Did you remove decoding from PHP? Does the page echo the correct URI?

Comment: _“but saves a blank image”_ - and what _exactly_ does that mean? You get an actual, _working_ image file of the same pixel dimensions, but it is “blank”? Or do you get a file that can not even be opened in an image viewer, and throws errors then already? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Just decode the data before manipulating it and don't manually replace data in base64.

```php
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");            // to get POST data
if($postdata)
{
  // print_r("came in postdata");
  // Get the data

  $imageData = urldecode( $postdata );

  // Remove the headers (data:,) part.
  // A real application should use them according to needs such as to check image type

  $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

  // $unencodedData= $imageData;
  // $filteredData = str_replace(' ', '+', $filteredData); 
  // Need to decode before saving since the data we received is already base64 encoded

  $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

  // echo "unencodedData".$unencodedData;

  // Save file. This example uses a hard coded filename for testing,
  // but a real application can specify filename in POST variable
  $fp = fopen( 'd:\\Apache2.4\\htdocs\\imgfile.png', 'wb' );
  fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
  fclose( $fp );
}
?>
```